# Get input value of inputfield that corresponds to map

Tags: apex, controller, repeat

Rendering a map that contains with key (location no), value (location name).

Rendering with a corresponding inputField where users will input the times they visited the corresponding location.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!setResetLocations}" var="locationKey">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-4">
            <apex:outputText value="{!setResetLocations[locationKey]}"></apex:outputText>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
            <apex:inputText class="form-control" value={!timesVisited} />
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

As the count of locations shown varies according to user, how should I tie the input value with the location in the controller when inserting into database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already gotten as far as using a map, go ahead and use another to map out the times visited:

```
public Map<String, Decimal> locationVisits { get; set; }

...

locationVisits = new Map<String, Decimal>();
for(String key: setResetLocations.keySet()) {
  locationVisits.put(key, 0);
}
```

Then, in your page:

```
        <apex:inputText class="form-control" value="{!locationVisits[locationKey]}" />
```

You could have also used a wrapper class instead of a map, but this works as well. **Make sure** that your locationVisits map contains all the same keys as your setResetLocations map, or you'll get a fatal Visualforce exception.

Comment: That's a really good idea, will give it a try.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I was to use a wrapper class instead, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: @Y12K You'd just have a class like `public class Location { public String locationNo { get; set; } public String locationName { get; set; } public Decimal timesVisited { get; set; } }`, then populate a `List<Location>`, and then iterate over that instead in your page. There's lots of examples on this site and others about how to do that.